# Compare void pointers in constexpr

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr, consteval

In C++:

1. It's OK to convert pointers to `void*` without a cast
2. It's OK to have 1-past-end pointers as long as you don't dereference them
3. It's OK to compare pointers with `==` and `!=` even though they point to unrelated objects.

In that case, why does this fail to compile:

```
consteval int test() {
    int* a = new int(42);
    long* b = new long(43);

    void* pa = &a + 1;
    void* pb = &b;


    int res = 0;
    if (pa == pb) res = 1;

    delete a;
    delete b;
    return res;
}  

int main() {
    return test();
}
```

Clang says:

```
subexpression not valid in a constant expression
    if (pa == pb) res = 1;
```

And GCC says:

```
 error: '(((void*)(&& test::a[1])) == ((void*)(& b)))' is not a constant expression
   10 |     if (pa == pb) res = 1;
      |         ~~~^~~~~
```

Neither is particularly useful. As far as I can tell, no UB is involved here. Is there a way to compare these pointers for equality without upsetting the compilers?

Comment: To supplement the dupe answer : http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5.25

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica so the relevant part is *"If one pointer represents the address of a complete object, and another pointer represents the address one past the last element of a different complete object, the result of the comparison is unspecified."*. Hmm. I am guessing there is no workaround in that case.